# Isometric fantasy action RPG game for the PC from the late 1990s

Tags: gaming, identify-this-game, pc

Please, help identify an old computer game.

- Year: 1995-1998 (possibly earlier, but no later than 2005).
- Genre: action RPG (or related)
- Theme: Fantasy.
- Platform: PC (Windows 95-98).
- Control: keyboard (+mouse?).
- View: isometric.
- Graphics: level of Diablo 1996 (but not this one), Baldur's gate 1998.

What I remember:

1. Skulls are drawn in the menu to the left and right of the menu items (this is not Mortal Kombat 4, and most likely not Clans 1999). The menu is in blue-gray or brown gloomy tones (but I'm not sure).
2. A male character runs through a forest location, runs up to mountains or a cave. Encounters a monster of large size, swamp color, similar to a troll (or something). Start a dialogue with him (at the same time, the text and the portrait of the troll are visible). This troll is either the king of the mountains or the master of the swamp (something like that). He offers to fight his son. His son stands a little further down the location in the cave. This is one of the side quests, it seems you can refuse it. At what stage of the main story this quest appears - I do not know
3. Maybe, the player was accompanied by a companion and ravens that helped him (but I strongly doubt that this is the Druid from Diablo 2).

Unfortunately, that's all. I will be grateful for tips.

P.S. Maybe it is Ancient Evil 1998, but I am not sure

Answer (score 4):

I think you're talking about *Blood Omen: Legacy of Kain*, released for Windows in 1997.

[image]

Fantasy action RPG; Male protagonist; Skulls; Blue tones; Oblique view but these stones look isometric.